# Showing results from drop down box in a table

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have this piece of code with me, I am trying to do sql queries from the drop down boxes.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"
                DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="a" DataValueField="a">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DB_firstConnectionString7 %>"
                SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [a] FROM [Table_1]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server"
                DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="b" DataValueField="b">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server"
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DB_firstConnectionString8 %>"
                SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [b] FROM [Table_1]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server"
                DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" DataTextField="c" DataValueField="c">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server"
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DB_firstConnectionString9 %>"
                SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [c] FROM [Table_1]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server"
                DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4" DataTextField="d" DataValueField="d">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource4" runat="server"
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DB_firstConnectionString10 %>"
                SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [d] FROM [Table_1]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                DataSourceID="SqlDataSource5">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="a" HeaderText="a" SortExpression="a" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="b" HeaderText="b" SortExpression="b" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="c" HeaderText="c" SortExpression="c" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="d" HeaderText="d" SortExpression="d" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="e" HeaderText="e" SortExpression="e" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="f" HeaderText="f" SortExpression="f" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource5" runat="server"
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DB_firstConnectionString11 %>"
                SelectCommand="SELECT [a], [b], [c], [d], [e], [f] FROM [Table_1] WHERE (([a] = @a) AND ([b] = @b) AND ([c] = @c) AND ([d] = @d))">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="a"
                        PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList2" Name="b"
                        PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList3" Name="c"
                        PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList4" Name="d"
                        PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have a small sql table and I want that upon selecting the values from drop down box, it should display results in that table. I am not able to do that. Any idea?

Comment: I cleaned up your code a bit.  It's hard to read it when it's not indented at all =)

Answer (score 1):

Your logic looks sound.

If you want the changes to be reflected as soon as you change the value of each `DropDownList`, you need to add the `AutoPostBack="True"` property to ***each of them***.  As an example, this is what the first one would look like:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="a" DataValueField="a">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

The only other thing I can see that would cause your table not to be filled out is if the SQL query for your `GridView` is being too restrictive.  Perhaps you meant to use `OR`s instead of `AND`s in your `WHERE` clause?

**EDIT:** One more thought here, it could be that your `GridView` is being databound *before* all of your `DropDownList`s have been databound.  This would cause them not to have SelectedValues yet, so your `ControlParameter`s would not have values when the `GridView` got databound.  You'll need to figure out a way to wait until all the `DropdownLists` are databound, and then use this code to re-bind your `GridView`:

```
SqlDataSource5.DataBind();
GridView1.DataBind();
```

*Hint: To check and make sure that this is your problem, you could put that code in the* `_DataBound` *event of **every one** of your* `DropDownList`*s.  Not very efficient, but it should work.*

Comment: there's no change in output..:/

Comment: @ankurkaushal I've added another possible solution to this asnwer.